# Anthy not working after upgrade to 14.10

Tags: 14.10, ibus, language-support, input-language, japanese

After upgrading to 14.10 Anthy (Japanese IME) is not working anymore. It just shows the Latin characters I type without converting anything. I already tried removing and reinstalling Japanese language support and removing/re-adding Anthy in the text entry settings. Is this a common problem? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I don't think it's a common problem. えあ絵tッ　(Sorry if I offended someone. I don't know what I typed.)

Comment: Can you select Anthy in the [input source indicator](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html#indicator)?

Comment: Yes I can. I can also activate it using Super+Space

Comment: Ok. As I tried to demonstrate, I can type using Anthy (I'm on 14.10). Is IBus selected in Language Support?

Comment: Yes, IBus is selected.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to solve it and if so, how?